# Заменить элементы главной диагонали

Tags: java

Есть такой код, знаю не самый лучший, но есть нужно переделать что бы он заменял  элементы главной диагонали каждой строки arsum'ом. Сейчас это частично но он заменяет немного не так

В данный момент он заменяет вот так 
а надо так

```
import java.io.*;

class MyCode {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][] array = new int[5][5];
        int arsum = 0;
        int k = 0;

        array[0][0] = -3;
        array[0][1] = 2;
        array[0][2] = -2;
        array[0][3] = 11;
        array[0][4] = -1;

        array[1][0] = 5;
        array[1][1] = -12;
        array[1][2] = -2;
        array[1][3] = 9;
        array[1][4] = -1;

        array[2][0] = 2;
        array[2][1] = -12;
        array[2][2] = -2;
        array[2][3] = 11;
        array[2][4] = -1;

        array[3][0] = 3;
        array[3][1] = 2;
        array[3][2] = -8;
        array[3][3] = -9;
        array[3][4] = 10;

        array[4][0] = 5;
        array[4][1] = -7;
        array[4][2] = 6;
        array[4][3] = -11;
        array[4][4] = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(array[i][j] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
                if (array[i][j] > 0) {
                    arsum = arsum + array[i][j];
                }
            }

            array[i][k] = arsum;
            k++;
            System.out.print(i + "\t строка - сумма положительных элементов =" + arsum + "\n");
            arsum = 0;
        }

        for (int n = 0; n < array.length; n++) {
            for (int m = 0; m < array[n].length; m++) {
                System.out.print(array[n][m] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Тебе нужно поменять значения диагонали, заменив их суммой значений по вертикали? Можешь показать что получилось, а что надо?

Comment: **"Заменяет так, а надо так"** -- как **"так"** надо? Переменную `k` можно выбросить -- она во втором цикле всегда равна `i`, а за пределами цикла не используется. Вместо `array[i][k] = arsum` можно написать `array[i][i] = arsum`

Comment: Нужно переделать - переделывайте, мы-то при чем?

Answer (score 1):

Сформулирую понятую мною постановку вопроса.

Имеем матрицу `n*n` в которой, по горизонтали высчитывается сумма всех положительных чисел и присваивается тому элементу, который принадлежит диагонали, по данной горизонтали, с левого верхнего угла матрицы до правого нижнего угла матрицы.

В вопросе обозначено три цикла.

1. Выводит заданные значения по горизонтали и вертикали
2. Высчитывает суммы положительных чисел по каждой горизонтали и присваивает полученные значения элементам по условию задачи
3. Выводит обновленную матрицу

[Ссылка на вывод](https://ideone.com/vVYYiO)

В том ли проблема у автора, что он использует три цикла?

Попробовал реализовать немного иначе, наверняка есть решение изящнее. Решил генерировать значения элементов в диапазоне от `min` до `max`.

```
Random randomez = new Random();
        int[][] array = new int[5][5];
        int min = -10;
        int max = 10;
        //int arsum = 0;
        //int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            int summaDiagonal = 0;   
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                array[i][j] = randomez.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
                if(array[i][i] < 0){
                        array[i][i] = 0;
                    }
                if (j != i) {
                    if(array[i][j] > 0){
                        summaDiagonal = array[i][j] + summaDiagonal;
                    }
                }
            }
            array[i][i] = summaDiagonal;
            for (int z = 0; z < array[i].length; z++) {
               System.out.print(array[i][z] + "\t\t");
                if(z == array[i].length - 1){
                   System.out.println();
                }
            }
        }
```

[На выходе](https://ideone.com/tgL7qE)

```
17      8       9       -4      -6 //17 =0 + 8 + 9, на месте 17 было отр число и мы его обнулили, что бы не складывать к отр числу
2       11      8       -5      1 //11 = 0 + 2 + 8 + 1
-6      -1      8       -1      8 //8 = 8 + 0
-9      -3      -1      7       7 //7 = 0 + 7
-10     1       -1      9       10 //10 = 1 + 9 + 0
```